# shortening if statement with same conditions

Tags: c#, dry

I'm comparing the `boolB` here twice, and this code looks like it needs improvement. Is it possible to write this different to reduce code repetition?

```
if (boolA)
{
  if (boolB)
  {
    return "A";
  }

  return "B";
} 

if (boolB)
{
   return "C";
}

return "D";
```

Comment: The actual logic can't really be reduced but if the booleans are method calls then you can just set temporary variables before this that store their result

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, you could a conditional operator to make it clearer - at least to my eyes:

```
return boolA && boolB ? "A"
    : boolA ? "B"
    : boolB ? "C"
    : "D";
```

Once you get used to this way of writing multiple conditional operators, it reads very clearly as a sort of pseudo-pattern-matching approach.

This *does* evaluate conditions multiple times, admittedly. There are ways of avoiding that, but I'm not sure they're nice... for example:

```
int bits = (boolA ? 2 : 0) | (boolB ? 1 : 0);
switch(bits)
{
    case 3: return "A";
    case 2: return "B";
    case 1: return "C";
    case 0: return "D";
    default: throw new InvalidOperationException("The world has gone mad!");
}
```

Or use a different approach to the nesting of the conditionals:

```
return boolA ? (boolB ? "A" : "B")
    : boolB ? "C"
    : "D";
```

This still *expresses* `boolB` as a condition twice, mind you.

Comment: `"still" evaluate conditions multiple times`? The original doesn't, but the conditional can evlauate `boolA` twice.

Comment: @Rawling: You're right - sorry, missed that for some reason.

Comment: I believe the short ternary expression is actually faster as well as shorter. http://stackoverflow.com/a/27440521/659190

Answer (score 2):

What about this? It uses the booleans to determine the index in the array.

```
string[] vals = new string[] { "A", "B", "C", "D" };

return vals[(boolA ? 0 : 2) + (boolB ? 0 : 1)];
```

Or, if a `char` is good too:

```
return (char)(65 /* 'A' */ + (boolA ? 0 : 2) + (boolB ? 0 : 1));
```

Comment: I was just writing a similar approach to this, but using a switch instead of creating an array...

Comment: @JonSkeet: I saw that. Nice option too. If the value is a char, you could even use the ASCII value.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Added that option too.

Comment: Damn, you just beat me to the `char` one. Although you can use `A` instead of `65` if you prefer without an extra cast.

Comment: @Rawling: `'A' + 11` gives an `int`... So you have to keep casting.

Comment: Yeah, I meant without having to do an *extra* cast, like `(int)'A'`.

Answer (score 1):

Slight variation of the posted answers avoiding all logical operations:

```
return new string(new[]
    {
        (char)('D' - ((Convert.ToInt32(boolA) << 1) | Convert.ToInt32(boolB)))
    });
```

**EDIT**

for what its worth, in my testing, run from the console and compiled in release mode. I get the following results.

Note, I had to alter Patrik Hofman's char arithmetic function to return a string.

Over `short.MaxValue * 100` iteration of evenly distributed test data I get these results,

```
TernaryShort:101ms
TernaryLong:102ms (1467515 ticks)
Original:102ms (1467551 ticks)
Lookup:104ms
ConvertChar:768ms
LogicalChar:953ms
```

This pattern is repeated consistently between executions.

So there is a real, but slim advantage in [Jon Skeet's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27440050/659190) short ternary expression, both in code size and code performance.